# How do we add Greek symbols as axis labels from matplotlib navigation tool?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to add greek symbols as axis labels for matplotlib plot. I know we can add those through the code before generating the plot. Is it possible to add these symbols from the navigation tool after generating plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is sure possible. You may open the "Figure options" dialogue and type in any [MathText](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) for the title or labels. E.g. in the picture below,

```
Title with $\alpha$
```

[image]